# Padd icons with empty space using linux convert utility

Tags: android, linux, image, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have a bunch of PNG icons with different sizes:

```
96x96
96x23
96x46
96x80
etc...
```

How can I, with the help of linux `convert` utility, padd them. So that all of the icons get the same square dimensions, say `96x96`.

The existing image should be centered. Like this (for the image of the size `5x5`):

```
.....
xxxxx
xxxxx
xxxxx
.....
```

I used the following command to scale the image. Maybe, I just forgot some parameter?

```
convert -size 96x96 icon.png -resize 96x96 +profile '*' scaled.png
```

Comment: Did you try my command meanwhile? What was the result?

Comment: Hi, sorry, right now I have no access to my linux laptop. I'll try this as soon as I'll get to it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should help:

```
convert             \
   icon.png         \
  -scale 96x96      \
  -background white \
  -gravity center   \
  -extent 96x96     \
  +profile '*'      \
   scaled.png
```

Comment: It just made image higher. Added white gap inside the image http://habrastorage.org/storage2/72f/d92/3d4/72fd923d4de4d2ffa7d69d84b110c74a.png

Comment: I've never experienced this. Can you please provide (a link to) the original PNG?

Comment: @OstapAndrusiv: The command works perfectly for me. ImageMagick version *6.7.6-9 2012-05-12 Q16*. GraphicsMagick version *1.3.16 2012-06-23 Q8*. Which one are yours?! -- Your linked image isn't even of size 96x96, it's 128x256. Are you sure you didn't somehow mix up the link to your output?

Comment: Probably, misspelled something in my bash script when tried that first time.